# Redirecting/forwarding based on url parameter

Tags: java, jsp

I have designed 3 jsp pages.

index.jsp, login.jsp and newUser. jsp

index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Ho there!</title>
</head>
<body>

This is authorization page.
<br>
<a href="/AgileScrumBoard/index.jsp?action=new">Create a new account</a>
<br>
<a href="/AgileScrumBoard/index.jsp?action=login">Login with the existing</a>
</body>
</html>
```

newUser and login are just plain-vanilla jsp pages.

Here the method doGet of the servlet:

```
String action=request.getParameter("action");
        if(action.equals("new")){
            response.sendRedirect("/newUser.jsp");
        }else if(action.equals("login")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else{
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }       
    }
```

The question is: why when I press on the links the request dispatcher doesn;t forward me/redirect me to the specified jsp pages?

PS: web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MainController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.MainController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

When I run my app at Tomcat: 
[image: At_tomcat]

Comment: Is request reaching your `doGet ` method after clicking link in browser?

Comment: Yes, the request reaches doGet method.

Comment: Can you share the URL with which you are accessing your index.jsp

Comment: http://localhost:8080/AgileScrumBoard/index.jsp

Comment: Are you using tomcat because your jsp doesn't have an application context

Comment: Could you elaborate on your point? What do you mean by saying "Are you using tomcat because your jsp doesn't have an application context"

Comment: If "AgileScrumBoard" is your web context root then try using `request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);` and `request.getRequestDispatcher("newUser.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Answer (score 0):

Both links redirect to index.jsp which is the page you're already in. Instead of /AgileScrumBoard/index.jsp add your servlet name. The link should redirect to the servlet then the servlet would redirect to login.jsp or newUser.jsp

Comment: nope, these links redirects to /login.jsp and /newUser.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your index.jsp code says:

```
<a href="/AgileScrumBoard/index.jsp?action=new">Create a new account</a>
<br>
<a href="/AgileScrumBoard/index.jsp?action=login">Login with the existing</a>
</body>
```

both links redirect to /AgileScrumBoard/index.jsp
I think the code should be:

```
<a href="yourservleturl?action=new">Create a new account</a>
<br>
<a href="yourservleturl?action=login">Login with the existing</a>
</body>
```